# which node.js embed database having a Browser based Console to watch the data

Tags: database, node.js, embed

1. I need a embed database which can run in process in a `node.js` server application.
2. the embed database should having both **inMemory** and file Mode.
3. the embed database should having a Browser based Console (or something others) to watch or edit the data.

Just like `h2-database` in *Java*

I do not care about which type of the database it is, Relational or NOSQL.

*What are the possible options?*

Answer (score 3):

Here are two potential candidates:

- *LevelDB* NodeJS Module : 
  https://github.com/rvagg/node-levelup

  *"Fast & simple storage - a Node.js-style LevelDB wrapper"*
- Memory-Only Back-end for the API : 
  https://github.com/rvagg/node-memdown

  *"A drop-in replacement for LevelDOWN that works in memory only"*

Comment: LevelUp in conjunction with LevelDown for no dependency, filesystem storage. And node-memdown for in-memory storage. @Roel van Uden is right. these are the way to go!